# How can I get children attribute + parent element

Tags: sql-server, openxml, sql-server-openxml

I would like to write a SQL Server stored procedure to parse XML data to retrieve the values:

```
DECLARE @Champs TABLE 
                (
                    NU_LINE VARCHAR(4), 
                    "KEY" VARCHAR(200), 
                    LABEL VARCHAR(200), 
                    API_NAME VARCHAR(200), 
                    API_FIELD VARCHAR(200), 
                    "VALUE" VARCHAR(MAX)
                );  

DECLARE @docHandle int;  
DECLARE @xmlDocument nvarchar(max); -- or xml type  

SET @xmlDocument = N'<STRUCTURE>
  <GRILLE>
    <ROWS>
      <ROW>
        <NU_LINE>1</NU_LINE>
        <CHAMPS>
          <CHAMP KEY="NUMBER" LABEL="AAA" API_NAME="AAA" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="ABC123" />
          <CHAMP KEY="RES" LABEL="AAA" API_NAME="AAA" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="JAMES" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_BEGIN" API_NAME="CCC" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="14/08/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_END" API_NAME="CCC" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="28/08/2021" />
         </CHAMPS>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <NU_LINE>2</NU_LINE>
        <CHAMPS>
          <CHAMP KEY="NUMBER" LABEL="ABC" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="CDE345" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_RES" LABEL="CDE" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="06/05/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="RES" LABEL="DEF" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="JOHN" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_BEGIN" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="07/08/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_END" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="14/08/2021" />
         </CHAMPS>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <NU_LINE>3</NU_LINE>
        <CHAMPS>
          <CHAMP KEY="NUMBER" LABEL="OOO" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="EFG567" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_RES" LABEL="OOO" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="10/05/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="RES" LABEL="OOO" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="JIM" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_BEGIN" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="24/07/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_END" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="31/07/2021" />
         </CHAMPS>
      </ROW>
    </ROWS>
  </GRILLE>
</STRUCTURE>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xmlDocument;  

-- Use OPENXML to provide rowset consisting of customer data.  
INSERT @Champs   
    SELECT *   
    FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, N'/STRUCTURE/GRILLE/ROWS/ROW/CHAMPS/CHAMP') 
    WITH (NU_LINE VARCHAR(4), "KEY" VARCHAR(200), LABEL VARCHAR(200), API_NAME VARCHAR(200), API_FIELD VARCHAR(200), "VALUE" VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT * FROM @Champs
```

But in my result `NU_LIGNE` is always null.

How can I do to get the NU_LINE 1, 2 or 3 respectively for each ROW ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why are you using those ancient procedures? SQL Server has supported XQUERY since 2005...

Comment: As for why, well the node `CHAMP` has no value `NU_LINE` so of course it returns `NULL`. `NU_LINE` is under the node `ROW`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, don't use those old procedures; they are there for compatibility for SQL Server **2000**. SQL Server has supported XQUERY since 2005, so there's no reason why you shouldn't be using it some 16 years later. If you do that, this is much more simple:

```sql
DECLARE @xmlDocument  xml; 
SET @xmlDocument = N'<STRUCTURE>
  <GRILLE>
    <ROWS>
      <ROW>
        <NU_LINE>1</NU_LINE>
        <CHAMPS>
          <CHAMP KEY="NUMBER" LABEL="AAA" API_NAME="AAA" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="ABC123" />
          <CHAMP KEY="RES" LABEL="AAA" API_NAME="AAA" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="JAMES" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_BEGIN" API_NAME="CCC" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="14/08/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_END" API_NAME="CCC" API_FIELD="BBB" VALUE="28/08/2021" />
         </CHAMPS>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <NU_LINE>2</NU_LINE>
        <CHAMPS>
          <CHAMP KEY="NUMBER" LABEL="ABC" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="CDE345" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_RES" LABEL="CDE" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="06/05/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="RES" LABEL="DEF" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="JOHN" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_BEGIN" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="07/08/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_END" API_NAME="DDD" API_FIELD="EEE" VALUE="14/08/2021" />
         </CHAMPS>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <NU_LINE>3</NU_LINE>
        <CHAMPS>
          <CHAMP KEY="NUMBER" LABEL="OOO" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="EFG567" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_RES" LABEL="OOO" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="10/05/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="RES" LABEL="OOO" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="JIM" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_BEGIN" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="24/07/2021" />
          <CHAMP KEY="DATE_END" API_NAME="FFF" API_FIELD="GGG" VALUE="31/07/2021" />
         </CHAMPS>
      </ROW>
    </ROWS>
  </GRILLE>
</STRUCTURE>';

SELECT R.R.value('(NU_LINE/text())[1]','int') AS NU_LINE,
       C.C.value('@KEY','varchar(200)') AS [KEY],
       C.C.value('@LABEL','varchar(200)') AS [LABEL],
       C.C.value('@API_NAME','varchar(200)') AS [API_NAME],
       C.C.value('@API_FIELD','varchar(200)') AS [API_FIELD],
       C.C.value('@VALUE','varchar(MAX)') AS [VALUE]
FROM @xmlDocument.nodes('/STRUCTURE/GRILLE/ROWS/ROW')R(R)
     CROSS APPLY R.R.nodes('CHAMPS/CHAMP')C(C);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=938459420eab10b1f40e37fd48512861)

Comment: Just realised they're artributes, not nodes. Fixed, @eric.bryan .